# How to stop Windows 7 from asking to format a disk?

Tags: windows-7, format, usb-flash-drive

I have this USB flash drive with a Linux partition that I use inside VirtualBox.

Each time I insert it into the USB port, windows keeps asking if it should format it.

Is there anyway to disable Windows from asking that?

Disabling auto-run has not resolved the problem unfortunately. Windows will still check if the disk contains a partition it knows about, and ask to format if it doesn't know it.

[image: RegEdit ScreenShot]

Really nice try though, any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Control Panel..Administrative Tools..Computer Management..Disk Management

Right-click on your drive and choose "Change Drive Letter and Paths", then choose "Remove".

Comment: Tested this under Windows 10 and works.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the registry key provided [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/hardware-devices/18872-prevent-windows-ask-format-my-external-drive.html) to disable Autoplay for removable drives...

**But, please note:** I haven't tested that regkey and can't vouch for what it does, and disabling Autoplay for *all* removable drives is a bit of a nuclear option.

Alas, that's all a Google search managed to turn up.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making it recognized after all by installing a file system driver, for example [Ext2 Installable File System For Windows](http://www.fs-driver.org/download.html), which also works with ext3